# VBA Inputbox not displaying string correctly?

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox

I'm trying to display a prompt using the VBA InputBox function. In the text of the InputBox, I include a string variable of a file name, however, when I run the code the string (called 'tempkey') is not displayed correctly- some of the string in the middle is missing.

I have went into the debugger an verified the 'tempkey' strings contents right before passing them to the input box. The string value is just not displayed correctly in the InputBox.

```
            tempkey = Left(GetFilenameFromPath(files(i)), Len(GetFilenameFromPath(files(i))) - Len("xxxxmap.xlsx"))

            If Not dict.Exists(tempkey) Then
                entry = InputBox("Please enter a short descriptor for: " & vbNewLine & tempkey & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "i.e. L5P-LM Post Thermal Cycle")
                If entry <> "" Then
                    dict(tempkey) = entry
                Else
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
```

The string 'tempkey' has a length of about 109 characters and includes no spaces.

Here is what the InputBox looks like:

[image: InputBox]

As you can see, everything in the 'tempkey' string after 'seq' and before 'from' is omitted from the InputBox..

Here is what my debugger looks like with the value of 'tempkey' just before the InputBox is displayed:

[image: DebugWindow]

Why is the string not displaying correctly?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does the InputBox line end in `above)_` and the watch window show `below)_`. I assume it's still the same issue, just different `files(i)`.

Comment: That's correct, they're are just different files. Same issue.

Comment: It looks like it's not adding line-breaks in the middle of a word (since all the text is joined by underscores up until "from below/above", it counts as one long word). You could just add spaces to your string. If that's impossible, you'd probably be best off using a custom user-form that you can edit to suit your needs.

Comment: It's a long shot, but I wonder if [`Application.InputBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox) has the same issue.

Comment: Can't reproduce with `MsgBox String(150, "x")` for example.  Can you update your question with an actual example of a text value which is not correctly displayed?

Comment: my guess would be that your string looks like a single word up to the space before "from" and the control is not wrapping but truncating and only wrapping when it gets to the space (seeming to indicate a new word).

Comment: Hmm @SmileyFtW good observation that does appear to be what is happening. That's weird that the input box functions that way. I guess it's an oversight in the coding of the input box form.

Comment: @JoshEller that does appear to be the problem. A shame that I have to modify my string to get this to work. Seems like bad design of the InputBox.

Comment: Count the characters that fit a line on the inputbox and implement a `vbCrLf`to break your string value from that point. Should be possible dynamically

Comment: Better to use your own userform I would think. You'll have complete control over it. The inputbox has limitations because it is meant to be a simple control for quick & dirty use.

Answer (score 0):

<s>InputBox strings are limited to 255 characters, so I would guess this is where the problem lies.</s>

Have you tried splitting tempkey into two seperate strings?

```
Dim s1 As String
Dim s2 As String
s1 = Left(tempkey, Len(s) / 2)
s2 = Right(tempkey, Len(s) / 2)

entry = InputBox("Please enter a short descriptor for: " & vbNewLine & s1 & s2 & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "i.e. L5P-LM Post Thermal Cycle")
```

Comment: The input box itself may be limited to 255 characters, but the message string is the issue and is less than 255.

Comment: @Jeff that doesn't appear to be the problem. The contents in the InputBox are less than 255 characters. The issue seems to be that my string contains a really long first "word" without any spaces, and InputBox does not handle that well; it cuts off the remaining characters of the word that don't fit within the fixed width of the InputBox.